# What Exactly Is The Benefit Of XMLHttpRequest Upload attribute?

Tags: javascript, upload, xmlhttprequest, progress, addeventlistener

I am trying to figure out what exactly the upload attribute does in the `XMLHttpRequest` object. It seems to me that with or without it, a `xhr` event listener for progress would monitor a `xhr.send(file)`.

I looked on W3C and found:
"The upload attribute must return the associated XMLHttpRequestUpload object.".

But I don't understand how this ties in with using `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressFunction, false);` since `xhr.addEventListener("progress", progressFunction, false);` would do the same thing.

I am asking because I am looking to create custom graphics for the progress of a an upload....I am **not** going to use HTML5 progress element or jquery. Strictly Javascript for the client side.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), "download events are fired on the `XMLHttpRequest` object itself (...) upload events are fired on the `XMLHttpRequest.upload` object". I'm not sure if they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequestUpload` object != `XMLHttpRequest` object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you attach the event to `xhr` itself, then it will only update `"progress"` when the upload is complete.

There's a difference between the `xhr` object, and the object which is used expressly for the upload.

Comment: wow, strange...i thought since upload was a **attribute** of XMLHttpRequest object they were of the same object.

Comment: Well, in the case of `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), upload = xhr.upload;` they aren't the same object -- under a type-inspection, `upload` is actually a `XMLHttpRequestUpload` object, according to Chrome. It also doesn't extend the `.open`, `.send`, et cetera, methods. It's an object which subscribes to progress on the native-level (browser-specific) code and calls updates on its event subscribers (to events like `onprogress|onloadstart|onloadend|onload|onerror|onabort`).  That's pretty much its entire job, as far as an end-user is concerned, I think. But it got around redoing the XHR API.

Comment: I would love more information about this topic, especially a link to a reference that covers the details.  I didn't see anything on MDN.